# How do i combine bulk-actions with actions on a list.

Tags: admin-on-rest

The latest beta has support for bulk actions, I can't understand how to combine them with none bulk, if i add actions prop the bulk action menu does not appear when i select grid rows.

Another question related to bulk actions, is it possible to have bulk actions for a datagrid populated using a reference many field?

Comment: What do you mean by none bulk? Please be more specific.